# Why does not the old image come to the image box to change?Asp.Net Mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have an image upload box. Normally, I enter the user information in my users table and add the profile photo and save it in the database. I click the Update button and display the user information. However, the profile photo does not appear in this box. It’s empty. The img path appears when I check it from the Console.log. But the existing image is not displayed on the update screen. If I click the update button without adding a new image, the default image is displayed and the user's image disappeared from the database. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a CORS-issue in the console?

Comment: @Nikolaus I don't have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check or inspect the user.ProfilePhotoPath value generated in the html. Check if the image path is correct.